# How do I describe what file filter I want using juce's FileFilter?

Tags: c++, juce, filefilter

I'm trying to have the browser only show audio files, however, I don't know what syntax to use to describe what file type I would like

```
fileChooser->setFileFilter(FileFilter(".wav"));
```

When I put this it says "Allocating an object of abstract class type 'juce::FileFilter'"

Sorry if this is an easy one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `WildcardFileFilter` instead, since `FileFilter` is an abstract base class:

```
fileChooser->setFileFilter(WildcardFileFilter("*.wav", "*", "somedescription"));
```

[Docs](https://juce.com/doc/classWildcardFileFilter).

Note that `setFileFilter` asks for a `const*`, meaning that you must manage it's lifetime.

At this moment, you're passing a temporary that will be destructed leaving the `fileChooser` with a dangling pointer, you should use something with a longer lifetime.

Comment: When I do this it says "No viable conversion from 'juce::WildcardFileFilter' to 'const juce::FileFilter *'"

Comment: @harry97uk Exactly, because you need to pass a pointer, not an object.

Comment: fileChooser->setFileFilter(WildcardFileFilter("*.wav"));   I put this and it says the same thing